# Search words either uppercase or lowercase and return uppercase or lowercase

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to search whether each word are either upper or lowercase and the result to reflect that. Needs to be written in XML file.

find:    `(?i)(?<!so and so many|.... shallow|hello)\Blo\b`

string `helo HELO`

substitute `llo` or `LLO`

all i am getting is `helllo HELllo`

Result i want is `hello HELLO`

I have tried to use various means to create if... then... else conditions and none will work.

Edit: corrected substitute.

Comment: Wait, if the input string is `hello HELLO`, that's exactly the same as the result you're looking for, right...?

Comment: No. I made some corrections.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that Boost regex lookbehind patterns must be of fixed length, your current one makes the pattern invalid. You would need to split the alternatives into separate lookbehinds.

Next, `\B` assumes you want to match `lo` inside a word only. Thus, the best approach here is to match and capture into separate groups a lowercase or an uppercase letter using capturing groups in a positive lookbehind, then, you will be able to check which group matched and apply the replacement logic as needed.

To make sure you match in a case sensitive way, you may wrap that lookbehind with a case modifier group, `(?-i:...)`.

Use

```
(?i)(?<!your...)(?<!words...)(?<=(?-i:([A-Z])|([a-z])))lo\b
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And replace with `(?{1}LO:?{2}lo)`.

So, if the letter before `lo` is lowercase, replace with `lo`, if it was uppercase, use `LO` as replacement.

[image]

Comment: Replace needs to be LLO and llo sorry. The example won't work in https://regex101.com/

Comment: @user10246830 Do **NOT** use regex101 to test this as it does not support Boost conditional replacement patterns. Only use it in Notepad++. If you need to replace with `llo` use this value in the replacement part instead of `lo`.

Comment: Does not work at all except for notepad++. I can not get it in the notepad++ xml file to be used by another software.

Comment: @user10246830 If you need to turn `helo HELO` to `hello HELLO`, you will get the expected result if you use `(?i)(?<!your)(?<!words)(?<=(?-i:([A-Z])|([a-z])))lo\b` and `(?{1}LLO:?{2}llo)` as replacement. If the `(?<!so and so many|.... shallow|hello)` lookbehind contains the whole words you want to avoid replacements in, use it after last `\b`: `(?i)(?<=(?-i:([A-Z])|([a-z])))lo\b(?<!\byour)(?<!\bwords)`

Comment: The replacement you gave will not work in my software, only worked in notepad++ which is no good. I must have `\B` The regex will be use to convert whole script/subtitles by converting usa spelling to uk spelling using a dictionary file. The above is a small example. Trying this out but not yet correct. https://regex101.com/r/jwc0eG/1/

Comment: @user10246830 What software? You only mentioned you were using Notepad++. If you use `(?<=(?-i:([A-Z])|([a-z])))`, you do not need `\B`, this lookbehind makes the regex match only if the `lo` is at the end of a 3+ letter word.

Comment: If the word is lo then it will return llo. \B returns lo. I do have it working but 2 lines of regex codes in my xml file. 1 line for uppercase and 1 line for lower case. Just trying to merge it into one line. I think it won't work as Subtitle Edit deosn't support Boost conditional replacement. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @user10246830 You are thinking it up, [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/d0MnxH/1) doesn't match `lo`.

Comment: That's because you have a space before lo. In subtitle file if lo is the start of the sentence there is no space and produced llo.

Comment: @user10246830 [It does not match a `log` at the start of the sentence](https://regex101.com/r/d0MnxH/3).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xC0wu2/1/ See the word `led` in the test string, remove `\B` then it will match and become `lled`, which i can not have because `led` is a word. This is the full xml code and have uppercase too. Just trying to merge the 2 into 1.

Comment: @user10246830 You are not following what I wrote in my answer. `\B` should be removed when you add `(?<=(?-i:([A-Z])|([a-z])))`. See [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC0wu2/3/). Now, where are you using this regex? Do you have any access to the code?

Comment: Sorry, i understand now. https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/blob/master/Dictionaries/eng_OCRFixReplaceList.xml In this i can use regex to convert all usa spelling to uk spelling from the dictionary file. Thus 167 words(matches) require an extra `l` before `led`. minor changes https://regex101.com/r/xC0wu2/4

Comment: @user10246830 you are using it in C# code. See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/fctf4k) showcasing my approach.

Comment: Great that worked. However it needs to go into the eng_OCRFixReplaceList.xml. At the bottom you see  <RegularExpressions>.